Text with multiple lines on top left of page (without fancyhdr)
I would like to add text to the top left of my document (without fancyhdr!) and be able to create different lines in the text.
My current MWE does not allow new lines (\ and \newline do not work inside \makebox and I have not had success with \parbox). I may have missed out on something.
I would like to be able to control how far from the left and top of the page the first letter in the text is.
Your help is appreciated in advance, thanks!

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{atbegshi,picture}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-17cm\relax,-0.75cm){\makebox[0pt][r]{\footnotesize Line 1, Line 2, Line 3}}%
}}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla

\end{document}


This is similar to this question: How can I add text in the top right corner of a page without using fancyhdr - just on the opposite side. For multiple lines, use \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l} ... \\ ... \\ ... \end{tabular}.

@Werner that worked! I can't accept your answer since you've commented. Feel free to "answer the question" and I will mark it as done.

is there a way to make it only appear on page 1?

You can use \ifnum\value{page}=1 <do something on page 1 only>\fi.

I tried that and it still shows up in every page.
MWE: {\ifnum\value{page}=1
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{
\put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-21.2cm\relax,-0.65cm){{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l}Line 1\ Line 2  \ Line 3\end{tabular}
}}
}}
\fi}

No, it should be \AtBeginShipout{... \ifnum\value{page}=1 \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}.

Makes sense. Thank you!

You can use a \parbox or minipage and replace the box with \usebox. For example,
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\newsavebox\mylhs
\sbox\mylhs{%
  \parbox{13cm}{\footnotesize
    \parindent=0pt
    Line 1\par Line 2\par Line 3%
  }%
}
% \AddToHook{shipout/background}{% foa all pages (until removed)
%   \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-17cm\relax,-0.75cm){%
%     \usebox\mylhs
%   }%
% }
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{% for this/the next page only
  \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth-17cm\relax,-0.75cm){%
    \usebox\mylhs
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bla

\end{document}


Note that packages such as atbegshi are no longer needed and generally just provide wrappers for backwards-compatibility since the kernel now provides hooks for a rewritten shipout routine.

Thank you! interesting output. Is there a way to make it appear only on page 1 using the MWE I shared?

@jrjrjr please see edit above.

thank you! appreciate your time.

@jrjrjr weldome! I'm a fan of the new hooks ;). so much easier than trying to remember which package does what with what syntax. [alternative reading: I'm too lazy to deal with the variety of approaches.]
